# inputAccessoryView appearing with animation after view appears in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, inputaccessoryview

I have an inputAccessoryView for text input in a chat app.  I implemented the inputAccessoryView using the following:

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
     get {
          setupInputToolbar()
          return inputToolbar
     }
}
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
     return true
}
```

This occurs in a viewController which is a childViewController.  I use a segmented control to display this chat viewController with the inputAccessoryView.

The problem I'm having is the inputAccessoryView will only display if I place self.becomeFirstResponder() in the viewDidAppear() of the chat viewController (child).

If I omit self.becomeFirstResponder() or place it in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear(), the inputAccessoryView does not display.

The problem with having it in viewDidAppear() is that it displays with an animation after the view is already on screen which is not what I want.

Comment: And did you try `viewWIllLayoutSubviews`?

Comment: where do you mean to put that?

Comment: you said "If I omit self.becomeFirstResponder() or place it in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear(), the inputAccessoryView does not display". Try putting it in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: And because it's called multiple times, check for `isFirstResponder` to not set it multiple times.

Comment: putting it in viewWillLayoutSubviews() still causes it to appear with an animation after the view is on screen

Comment: yes, I tried that also with if !self.isFirstResponder() in viewWillLayoutSubviews() but still appearing with animation after view on screen.

Comment: Are you subclassing UITextField?

Comment: I'm using a UITextView inside a toolbar which I set up in the inputAccessoryView getter. I've modified the question to reflect that.

Comment: my inputTextView is a UITextView  which is setup in the setupInputToolbar() method.  It is not subclassed

Comment: When you call `self.becomeFirstResponder() `, what is `self`, your view controller? If yes, why don't you call `becomeFirstResponder() ` on your textView?

Comment: self is the chat viewController.  when I call it textView.becomeFirstResponder() there is no inputAccessoryView displayed.  I believe the problem is because I'm using a childViewController in a container.  It does not allow the child or any element within it to become firstResponder until it is displayed.

Comment: There is a `UIViewController` method `didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?)` method, when your child view controller loads in parent view controller that is called. You can try it, otherwise I am not able to help, because I am not properly understanding your problem.

Comment: that also displays the inputAccessoryView but only with animation after the view is on.  thanks for your help.  I'll keep working at it.

Comment: Why don't you just assign inputToolbar to textView. inputAccessoryView? Then it will appear any time when the text view become first responder.

Answer (score 3):

I accomplished this by first adding a `viewHasPerformedSubviewLayoutAtLeastOnce` property to the ViewController.

```
private var viewHasPerformedSubviewLayoutAtLeastOnce = false
```

Making `canBecomeFirstResponder` dependent on the above property.

```
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return viewHasPerformedSubviewLayoutAtLeastOnce
}
```

Then updating that property in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and becoming first responder inside a `UIView.performWithoutAnimation` block.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    if viewHasPerformedSubviewLayoutAtLeastOnce == false {
        viewHasPerformedSubviewLayoutAtLeastOnce = true
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation { becomeFirstResponder() }
    }
}
```

It all feels a little hacky, but it results in the view appearing without any animations.

Comment: This works and fixes a problem with MessageKit and InputAccessoryView, but it can happen with just returning a UIView() in `func inputAccessoryView()` as well, so it seems to be a UIKit bug under certain conditions.

Comment: This works but the inputAccessoryView is added as soon as the viewController is pushed which looks really bad... (but i couldn't find any better way of doing it)