# Glitching presentation animation when pushing UIViewController with inputAccessoryView onto UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am building a Swift chat app that has a typical bottom docked view containing the text field like WhatsApp or Facebook Messenger. I am following the approach of providing a custom `inputAccessoryView` from the `ChatViewController`.

The problem is, when I push the `ChatViewController` to the `UINavigationController` I am seeing a glitchy flashy animation where the `inputAccessoryView` is first shown for a split second in the parent, then lags in while the pushed view controller is being presented. I struggled to capture this in a video so you can  see the important parts of the sequence of events here:

| Before the push | Input view flickers into parent | Input view lagging behind | Final State Is Correct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Before the push action] | [image] | [image] | [image] |

Check out the code below for the smallest possible class that recreates this issue:

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    let accessoryView = UIView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        accessoryView.frame.size.height = 80
        accessoryView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
    
    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return accessoryView
    }
}
```

Here is how the `UIViewController` is shown:

```
let chatViewController = ChatViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: true)
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: have you try change the animated to false? `navigationController?.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: false)`

Comment: This should accomplish what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46690918/inputaccessoryview-appearing-with-animation-after-view-appears-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one. I think your best bet is becoming the first responder after the `ChatViewController` view appears. Checkout `viewDidAppear` and `canBecomeFirstResponder`. A potential downside is that there will be an animation when the `inputAccessoryView` appears.

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    let accessoryView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        accessoryView.frame.size.height = 80
        accessoryView.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    var readyToBecomeFirstResponder = false
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        readyToBecomeFirstResponder = true
        becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        readyToBecomeFirstResponder
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return accessoryView
    }
}
```

If you don't like the animation you can get rid of it by moving the flag to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
class ChatViewController: UIViewController {
    let accessoryView = NewView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        accessoryView.frame.size.height = 80
        accessoryView.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    var readyToBecomeFirstResponder = false
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        if !readyToBecomeFirstResponder {
            readyToBecomeFirstResponder = true
            UIView.performWithoutAnimation { becomeFirstResponder() }
        }
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        readyToBecomeFirstResponder
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return accessoryView
    }
}
```

NOTE: I can't take full credit for the second solution. This post helped me out with that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52450073/4081597